# pushViewController cause autoLayout issue using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed (iphone6)

Tags: ios, autolayout, pushviewcontroller

I have a `FirstViewController` with `TabBarController` and `NavigationController`
(TabBarController > NavigationController > UIViewController)

When pressing the `UIButton` on the `firstViewController`, it will push to the `SecondViewController`.

```
SecondViewController *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BVC"];

vc2.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

In `SecondViewController` there is an `UILabel` on the lower right corner with Constraints - ( Width-Equal, Height-Equal, TrailingSpaceToSuperView = 16,BottomSpaceToBottomLayoutGuide = 20 )

The result work fine on iphone4s(IOS7), but on iphone6(IOS8.1) the `UILabel` will first appear on the lower right corner plus a "BottomBar height" about 1 second then will update to the correct place (BottomSpaceToBottomLayoutGuide = 20)

When I set the `pushViewController` animated to NO, `UILabel` will show on the correct place immediately.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:NO];
```

Anyone encounter the same issue?

Comment: when this happen to me I fix it by reseting constraints or I leave it up to XCOde suggestions to apply constraints

Comment: yeah, thanks for your advice. Although, when it comes to a View on the button of the screen (Height-Equals TrailingSpace, LeadingSpace, bottomSpace), the suggestion don't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solve this issue. Select bottom of the BottomSpaceToBottomLayoutGuide Constraint.

[image]

Comment: Hidden in Xcode 7, but still works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021129/constrain-view-bottom-to-superview-bottom-not-bottomlayoutguide-in-storyboard/33432500#33432500

Answer (score 0):

@Jenny's approach now is hidden in Xcode 7, but you can open your storyboard as a source code, find this constraint and manually set it to "bottom". To simplify search just copy its ObjectID from the Identity Inspector.