# constrain view.bottom to superview.bottom not bottomLayoutGuide in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

In interface builder it only gives me the option of constraining my sub view to the bottom layout guide, not the superview. Because I am sometimes using the controller as a child controller in a container controller setup, I really want to constraint to the superview bottom, not the bottom layout guide.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select your TableView and go to `Editor -> Pin`.
From there you have 4 options to pin to superview:

- Leading Space to Superview
- Trailing Space to Superview
- Top Space to Superview
- Bottom Space to Superview

[image]

This works as expected. The only downside is that you have to perform the pinning manually, as there are no shortcuts available.

Comment: So difficult to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 55):

As @Trianna Brannon pointed out, [the approach in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021160/11635) no longer works in Xcode7. In Xcode7 you have to right click your element, draw a line to the bottom until the constraint selector pops up.

[image: Constraint selector]

**Then press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and now you'll get the desired Bottom constraint:**

[image]

Comment: For me it's draw a line to the main `View` then `alt` to show the options.

Comment: This also solves the noticeable delay or lag on hiding tabbar via hidesBottomBarWhenPushed when the view is constrained to its parent view's bottom.