# Q：I got an issue with navigationController push

Tags: ios, animation, push, uitabbar

Somebody run into this issue?
When I from a `UIViewController` push to a storyboard-base `viewController` and hidden the `BottomBar`, the storyboard-base `viewController` first come a white bottom, and the storyboard-base `viewController`'s bottom controls move down at once, covered the white blank space.Some friends know why it appear? And how to solve this issue?

The code is here:

```
 InformationCollectionViewController *info = [self.sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InformationCollectionViewController"];
 info.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];
```

BTW:If I set `[self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:NO];`
there will not show that issue.

Answer (score 0):

1.When you set animated NO, it will display the last state of view.
2.If you layout some views to bottom layout guide, you will see bottom bar at the beginning of animation. If you layout to the top level view, you won't get this issue.

Comment: Your answer is right,but , because I use autolayout to layout my views, there have 2 views to base-on Bottom Layout Guide, I should how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @LeoMaer When you add layout,you can choose which you want to layout to.

Comment: The 2 views's bottom constrains.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by refering to :[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021129/constrain-view-bottom-to-superview-bottom-not-bottomlayoutguide-in-storyboard/33432500#33432500)

And there is some different with the reference.
In the `info` controller:the `view` I want to constraint, only should change the bottom constraint.Before Xcode 7,the solution maybe this:[constrain view.bottom to superview.bottom not bottomLayoutGuide in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021129/constrain-view-bottom-to-superview-bottom-not-bottomlayoutguide-in-storyboard/29021160#29021160)
But after Xcode7, my solution is worked.

My solution is:

1.Press `Ctrl` and drag the `view` which I want to constraint to the    `info` controller's `View`, which is in left column.Then show the `constraints picker`.

2.Then I press `ALT`, to show the other `constraints`, contains the `Bottom Space to Container Margin`,now you should do is choose it.

3.Then you can edit the `Bottom Margin Alignment Constraint`, make sure

First Item:`Superview.Bottom Margin`
Relation:`Equal`
Second Item:`YourView.Top`

BTW:Thx @Lumialxk , thanks about your enlightenment for this question.